# The ideal way to detect a raspberry pi from java (jar)

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, hardware

Hello I would like to know which is the ideal way to detect if a jar/java program is running on raspberry pi or not.

Why do I want that? I want to use the watchdog in the raspberry pi but also I use the java program from windows which doesn't or doesn't require the watchdog.

Is there a way to detect if the jar is running on a raspberry the same way some people detect the operative system?

The same way people use that...

```
class ShowProperties {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.getProperties().list(System.out);
    }
}
```

Comment: `System.getenv("PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER")` get's the processor's name. What does it return on a Pi?

Comment: it returns null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to work out details of the operating system your JVM is running on by testing the values of these Java system properties:

- `os.name`   Operating system name
- `os.arch`   Operating system architecture
- `os.version`    Operating system version

Use `System.getProperty(name)` to fetch the value of a system property.

---

If that isn't sufficiently precise, then you need to resort to non-portable solutions, such as using `System.exec(...)` to run `uname -1` or similar.

Note: the "raspberrypi" you see on your system is actually the default hostname, and is not a reliable indicator.  (It will often be set by the user to something else.)

Comment: I think that does not helps much. It gives the following information :-
`Linux
4.1.19+
arm`

Instead uname -a on command line gives following info :-

`Linux raspberrypi 4.1.19+ #858 Tue Mar 15 15:52:03 GMT 2016 armv6l GNU/Linux` . Now I was wondering if there is some way to read information from some sysfs or procfs.

Answer (score 4):

Here is some code from one of my helper classes.  Notice how ***isPiUnix*** is set to true.  This technique relies on the PRETTY_NAME or NAME value in the os-release file. Tweak necessary to detect any variations of your supported systems.  Note that ***isLinux*** and ***isPiLinux*** will both return true when running on the Pi which is expected.  You only need to test for ***isPiLinux***.

```
private static boolean isWindows       = false;
private static boolean isLinux         = false;
private static boolean isHpUnix        = false;
private static boolean isPiUnix        = false;
private static boolean isSolaris       = false;
private static boolean isSunOS         = false;
private static boolean archDataModel32 = false;
private static boolean archDataModel64 = false;

static {
    final String os = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
    if (os.indexOf("windows") >= 0) {
        isWindows = true;
    }
    if (os.indexOf("linux") >= 0) {
        isLinux = true;
    }
    if (os.indexOf("hp-ux") >= 0) {
        isHpUnix = true;
    }
    if (os.indexOf("hpux") >= 0) {
        isHpUnix = true;
    }
    if (os.indexOf("solaris") >= 0) {
        isSolaris = true;
    }
    if (os.indexOf("sunos") >= 0) {
        isSunOS = true;
    }
    if (System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model").equals("32")) {
        archDataModel32 = true;
    }
    if (System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model").equals("64")) {
        archDataModel64 = true;
    }
    if (isLinux) {
        final File file = new File("/etc", "os-release");
        try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
             BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis))) {
            String string;
            while ((string = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if (string.toLowerCase().contains("raspbian")) {
                    if (string.toLowerCase().contains("name")) {
                        isPiUnix = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Building on Java42's answer here is a complete helper class.

**Usage in Java code**

```
if (Raspberry.isPi()) {
 ...
}
```

**Test result**

```
javac Raspberry.java
java Raspberry
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"
```

**Raspberry.java**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

/**
 * Raspberry PI helper class
 * @author wf
 *
 */
public class Raspberry {

  public static boolean debug = false;

  /**
   * check if this java vm runs on a raspberry PI
   * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37053271/the-ideal-way-to-detect-a-raspberry-pi-from-java-jar
   * 
   * @return true if this is running on a Raspbian Linux
   */
  public static boolean isPi() {
    String osRelease = osRelease();
    return osRelease != null && osRelease.contains("Raspbian");
  }

  /**
   * read the first line from the given file
   * 
   * @param file
   * @return the first line
   */
  public static String readFirstLine(File file) {
    String firstLine = null;
    try {
      if (file.canRead()) {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(fis));
        firstLine = bufferedReader.readLine();
        fis.close();
      }
    } catch (Throwable th) {
      if (debug)
        th.printStackTrace();
    }
    return firstLine;
  }

  /**
   * get the operating System release
   * 
   * @return the first line from /etc/os-release or null
   */
  public static String osRelease() {
    String os = System.getProperty("os.name");
    if (os.startsWith("Linux")) {
      final File osRelease = new File("/etc", "os-release");
      return readFirstLine(osRelease);
    }
    return null;
  }

  /**
   * entry point to call from command line
   */
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    if (isPi()) {
      System.out.println(osRelease());
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Stephen C said you can use the os.* properties.

You may run the uname -a from inside your Java app, but that is probably a bad idea because the format varies wildly. My RPI2 running OMC (media player distro) I get with your code:

```
os.arch=arm
os.name=Linux
os.version=4.4.6-3-osmc
```

and uname -a reports:

```
Linux osmc 4.4.6-3-osmc #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Apr 1 20:55:03 UTC 2016 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Also you can give a look at the PI4J project. They have an [example](http://pi4j.com/example/system-info.html) that outputs info about the PI it is running. Try to see the code on how do they do it.

Answer (score 0):

this function will detect if is RasberryPi

```
private static StringBuilder StringBuilderResult;

private static boolean DetectRaspBPi() {
    GetInfoByExecuteCommandLinux("cat /proc/device-tree/model", false);
    return StringBuilderResult.toString().toLowerCase().contains("raspberry");
}

private static void GetInfoByExecuteCommandLinux(String command, boolean getList){
    try {
        Process pb = new ProcessBuilder("bash", "-c", command).start();
        BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(pb.getInputStream())
        );
        String line;
        if (getList){
            ListStringBuilderResult = new ArrayList<>();
        } else {
            StringBuilderResult = new StringBuilder();

        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            if (getList){
                ListStringBuilderResult.add(line);
            } else {
                StringBuilderResult.append(line);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```